# discover live hosts by partial hostname

Tags: ping, hostname

my current problem is that I want to ping all the systems that start with given set of characters and get the systems that are responsive to a text file. I do not know the complete hostnames, I just know they start with a specific set of letters.

For example, I want to ping all the systems that start with 'DIM' from the entire network.

Is something like this possible?

thanks a lot for any help!